# Unbiased estimator for mu

Tags: probability

> I have to find an unbiased estimator for $\mu$ where $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)$ is the mean for a $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$-distribution.

I know that unbiased requires $E[\bar{X}] = \mu$ in this case but I am not sure whether or not my calculations are correct:

$$
E[\bar{X}] = E[\frac{1}{n}(X_1+X_2+...+X_n)] = \frac{1}{n} E[X_1+X_2+...+X_n] = \frac{1}{n} E[X_i] = \frac{1}{n} \mu = \mu.
$$
Thus $E[\bar{X}] = \mu$ and therefore $\bar{X}$ must be an unbiased estimator for $\mu$. Is this correct?

---

Furthermore I need to calculate the MSE. Thus I need to find 
$$
E[(\bar{X}-\mu)^2] = Var(\bar{X}-\mu) + (E[\bar{X} - \mu ])^2 = Var(\bar{X}) = Var(\frac{1}{n} ( x_1+x_2+...+x_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot Var(x_i) = \frac{1}{n} \cdot Var(x) \cdot n = \frac{1}{n} \cdot Var(x) = \frac{1}{n}.$$ 
Is this also correct?

---

I do not have answers to the above questions and I am currently studying for my exam in probability and statistics.

Thanks in advance everyone for your help.

Comment: How is $\frac1n\mu=\mu$?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I guess it's because there are 2 sum signs missing in the equations

Answer (score 3):

You have dropped the sum in both calculations. You should have: 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \mu$$
and
$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n Var(X_i) =\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n 1 = \frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. However can you explain why $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \mu$? Is the sum just equal to n? Same for the variance. Thanks.

Comment: @MathiasNissen Since $\mu$ does not depend on the sum index, you get $\sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \mu \sum_{i=1}^n 1 = n\mu$